# file_put_contents only outputs a single file?

Tags: php

Collating some data week by week I serialized an array of the appropriate data and output that to a temporary file using file_put_contents.

Inclusive of some output statements to try and establish what is happening the code looks like this:

```
    echo "<br/> collate session data <br/>";
    print_r($this->session_Data);
    $serialized_Array = serialize($this->session_Data);
    $file_Name =  'session_Data_' . $this->week_Number;
    echo "file_Name: " . $file_Name; 
    file_put_contents($file_Name, $serialized_Array);
```

The file name definitely gets updated appropriately and there is definitely data to output.

But this will only ever output the first weeks data to the tmp file.

I get no permission errors I get status 200 OK but no files are created.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: You get status 200 on your browser because the script is loaded, the function just returns FALSE. Check permissions, I'm 100% sure you don't have enough permissions.

Comment: ok I am going back and reviewing this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the file in the same directory as the script. In a default configuration the webserver process has only read and execute rights in that directory.

- create a separate directory for the files, and give the webserver process write permission to that folder.
- give the webserver process write permission to the folder the script is in. Be aware that this can be a security issue.

Comment: I have had a go at this but thus far I still just get the 1 file in the new directory. I will have to rethink what I am doing here.

Comment: perhaps you should add a extra number to the file name. If the file exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: Oh yes I know that that is why I was using week numbers as a suffix. Anyway I have it sort now using your approach.